# convert double quote string to string array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, str-replace, string-function

How can I convert below string,

```
"[""1"",""2"",""3""]"
```

To this,

```
["1","2","3"]
```

I have try this without success:

```
Replace(string, """", "")
```

Comment: The title says that you want to create an array yet your actual question indicates something else.  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the issue.  I'm sure it's easy to fix but we need to actually understand the specifics.  Do you really have a `String` that contains that first value or is that just what you see represented in VS?  The fact is that if you have a `String` that contains that second value then VS will visualise that as the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vb.net - you should try like this,

```
 Dim stringVar As String = "[""1"",""2"",""3""]"
 stringVar.Replace("""", "")
```

Also check [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace-vbnet) to use Replace function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you can try something like this :

```
Dim s As String = "[""1"",""2"",""3""]"
Dim collection As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s, "\d+")

Dim svals As String = ""
For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In collection
    If svals = String.Empty Then
         svals = m.Value
    Else
         svals = svals & "," & m.Value
    End If

Next

Dim rr() As String 

rr = svals.Split(",") ' Result as array of string
```

[`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CxFe28)